# using set to extract a matched pattern using ' as pattern separator

Tags: sed, pattern-matching

I'm just not getting my head around the pattern matching in sed, what is worse, there are quotes as separators.

I do:

```
 cat file | grep \'*.s\'
```

and get:

```
'PhaseRayA:      '       'sca/sca_out/sc_ray_a.s'
'PhaseRayO:      '       'sca/sca_out/sc_ray_o.s'
```

as output. An now I want to extract the:

```
sca/sca_out/sc_ray_a
sca/sca_out/sc_ray_o.s.s
```

So my pattern would be '*.s', with the quotes being part of the pattern but not part of the wanted result.

Any ideas on that? I guess sed will du the job but have no clue how...
Thanks for any help...
All the best, André

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little ambiguous, but this should do what I think you mean:

```
sed -e "s/'[^']*' *'//" -e "s/'//" file
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider awk:

```
$ cat test.txt
'PhaseRayA:      '       'sca/sca_out/sc_ray_a.s'
'PhaseRayO:      '       'sca/sca_out/sc_ray_o.s'

$ awk -F "'" '{print $4}' test.txt
sca/sca_out/sc_ray_a.s
sca/sca_out/sc_ray_o.s
```

I tend to use sed to edit files and awk to process them. awk is built for breaking up records.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
sed "s/.*'\([^']*\)'/\1/" inputfile
```

Similarly:

```
sed 's/.*\o47\([^\o47]*\)\o47/\1/' inputfile    # that's the letter "o" between the backslash and the 4
```

or

```
sed 's/.*\x27\([^\x27]*\)\x27/\1/' inputfile
```